# Bootstrap 3.0.0 nav vertical collapse responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, vertical-alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

After many search without results, I try to send a post.

I'm looking for a way for the nav-stacked (vertical menu) from bootstrap 3.0.0 (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) or my sidebare becomes collapsed when tablet or smartphone is used (such as navbar).

I'm agree to use other component that nav-stacked if the result is a vertical responsive menu.

My code

```
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="sidebar" >
            <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#888;color:#fff;" data-target="#test">Sidebar</div> 
            <div class="panel-body" id="test">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

            </ul>

              <hr>

            <div class="col col-span-12">
              <i class="icon-2x icon-facebook"></i>&nbsp;
              <i class="icon-2x icon-twitter"></i>&nbsp;
              <i class="icon-2x icon-linkedin"></i>&nbsp;
              <i class="icon-2x icon-pinterest"></i>
            </div>

            </div><!--/panel body-->
          </div><!--/panel-->
        </div><!--/end left column-->
```

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Check out this article: [Creating a RWD Off-Canvas Layout with Bootstrap 3](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-11-05/creating-a-rwd-off-canvas-layout-with-bootstrap-3.aspx "Created a RWD Off-Canvas Layout with Bootstrap 3")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is that it ?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="panel-heading">Sidebar22</div>
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>              
            </ul>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>

</div><!--/end left column-->

<div class="col-md-10">
</div>
```

Check [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4Bb8/) out.

Comment: Perfect. The last problem is how close it by default on mobile ?

Comment: I'm sorry, would you would you rephrase it?

Comment: The problem is by default the menu is unwrap. How should I do to wrap the menu by default on mobile ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s4Bb8/27/ - By default Bootstrap will close it based on the screen size.

Comment: The problem here is that the menu title is on the menu, not on the navbar header, if you move it to the navbar header, it will mess up the menu.